# Merge records in mysql table using Laravel (or not)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am tracking a users activity while not logged in with a cookie_id and grouping these by date. When the user logs in I want to transfer all records from their cookie_id to their user_id. The cookie_id and user_id dates can overlap if the user is using different machines throughout the day.

For example, a user with a user_id of 1 logs in from work, but from home she doesn't so we assign her a cookie_id of 123.

The table data could look like this.

```
id  user_id  cookie_id  date
2   1        NULL       2015-09-07
18  1        NULL       2015-09-10
19  NULL     123        2015-09-10
21  NULL     123        2015-09-11
22  1        NULL       2015-09-11
24  NULL     123        2015-09-12
```

Finally, one fine Saturday, she decides to log into her account from home.

What I would like to do is merge all of the records that have a coresponding user_id / date record, and update the row with a cookie_id of 123 with the user_id of 1 grouping by date creating any new records that are needed. I'd also like the related bananas table to be updated apprpriately as well.

```
id  user_id  cookie_id  date
2   1        NULL       2015-09-07
18  1        NULL       2015-09-10
22  1        NULL       2015-09-11
24  1        NULL       2015-09-12
```

I am using Laravel and would like to use query builder. I have all of the code except the database query working. I am happy to post it up, if anybody thinks it is useful.

My table structure is below and I have made a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b4f7/2).

**banana_groups**

```
id int(10),
user_id int(10),
cookie_id varchar(255),
date date NOT NULL,
```

**bananas**

```
id int(10),
banana_group_id int(10),
monkey_id int(10),
```

**EDIT**

To embrace the spirit of SO and in response to vho's comment (which mysteriously disappeared), here is my attempt to write this SQL. Needless to say, it is incomplete and doesn't work.

```
Select *
FROM banana_groups AS m
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM banana_groups WHERE m.user_id = 2)
AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM banana_groups WHERE ...
```

Comment: How do you know that a user_id of 1 and a cookie id of NULL corresponds to the same user as a user_id of NULL and a cookie_id of 123 when there is no record containing both user_id 1 and cookie_id 123?

Comment: The `cookie_id` is stored on every user's computer when they use the tool, if they are not logged in. We know the `cookie_id` belongs to the `user_id` once the user signs in. At that point I'd like to move all of the `cookie_id` settings over to the `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a stored procedure to do this. I will leave the question unanswered so if anybody knows how to do this without a stored procedure I mark their answer correct.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `transfer_bananas`(IN _cookieId VARCHAR(255), IN _userId INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE v_id INT;
DECLARE v_user_id INT;
DECLARE v_date DATE;
DECLARE v_done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur_banana CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id, `date`, (SELECT id from banana_groups
        WHERE user_id = _userId AND
        `date` = q.date) AS userId FROM banana_groups AS q
        WHERE cookie_id = _cookieId;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done = 1;
    OPEN cur_banana;
      loop_banana: LOOP
        FETCH cur_banana INTO v_id,v_date, v_user_id;
        IF v_done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE loop_banana;
        END IF;
        IF(v_user_id IS NULL) THEN
                UPDATE
                    banana_groups
                SET
                    user_id = _userId,
                    cookie_id = NULL
                WHERE
                    id = v_id;
            ELSE
            UPDATE
                bananas
            SET
                banana_group_id = v_user_id
            WHERE
                banana_group_id = v_id;
                DELETE FROM
                    banana_groups
            WHERE
                id = v_id;
            END IF;
      END LOOP loop_banana;
    CLOSE cur_banana;
END
```

I call it from Laravel with

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('CALL transfer_bananas(\'' 
  . $cookie_id 
  . '\', '
  . $user->id 
  .');'
));
```